# How to properly plot the pdf of a beta function in scipy.stats

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, probability

I am trying to fit a beta distribution to some data, and then plot how well the beta distribution fits the data. But the output looks really weird and incorrect.

```
import scipy.stats as stats 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.9999999 , 0.9602287 , 0.8823198 , 0.83825594, 0.92847216,
       0.9632976 , 0.90275735, 0.8383094 , 0.9826664 , 0.9141795 ,
       0.88799196, 0.9272752 , 0.94456017, 0.90466917, 0.8905505 ,
       0.95424247, 0.781545  , 0.9489085 , 0.9578988 , 0.8644015 ])
beta_params = stats.beta.fit(x)
print(beta_params)
#(3.243900357315478, 1.5909897101396109, 0.7270083219563888, 0.27811444901271615
 
beta_pdf = stats.beta.pdf(x, beta_params[0], beta_params[1], beta_params[2], beta_params[3])

print(beta_pdf)
#[2.70181543 6.8442073  4.98204632 2.82445508 6.76055614 6.75910611
 #5.90419012 2.82696622 5.58521916 6.34096675 5.2508072  6.73212694
 #6.98854653 5.98225724 5.36937625 6.9519977  0.67812362 6.99116729
 #6.89484982 4.10113147]

plt.plot(x, beta_pdf)
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with the answer  below, but just on a side note here--you can actually pass all those beta params to the stats.beta.pd() function with this code:  
`beta_pdf = stats.beta.pdf(x, *beta_params)`    Then, it doesn't matter how long the list off beta_params is, each will be passed into the function.  If you just add that asterisk, you can pass lists of args into functions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a statistician, but looking at your code I see that `x` is unordered.

Does sorting `x` before fit helps you?

```
x = np.sort(x)
beta_params = stats.beta.fit(x)
```

Doing so, you'd get this:

[image]